# Don't understand why "operation writes a value happens before an operation that reads that value" in chapter 5.3.1 in <C++ Concurrency in action>

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-model, happens-before

I currently read about "C++ Concurrency in action", in the memory model part (Chapter 5).
In chapter 5.3.1, the author writes:

```
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> data;
std::atomic<bool> data_ready(false);

void reader_thread()
{
    while(!data_ready.load())    // （1）
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep(std::milliseconds(1));
    }
    std::cout<<”The answer=”<<data[0]<<”\n”;    // （2） 
}

void writer_thread()
{
    data.push_back(42);  // （3）
    data_ready=true;     // （4） 
}
```

> Leaving aside the inefficiency of the loop waiting for the data to be
> ready （1）, you really need this to work, because otherwise sharing data
> between threads becomes impractical: every item of data is forced to
> be atomic. You’ve already learned that it’s undefined behavior to have
> nonatomic reads （2） and writes （3） accessing the same data without an
> enforced ordering, so for this to work there must be an enforced
> ordering somewhere.
>
> The required enforced ordering comes from the operations on the std::
> atomic variable data_ready; they provide the necessary ordering
> by virtue of the memory model relations happens-before and
> synchronizes-with. The write of the data （3） happens-before the write
> to the data_ready flag （4）, and the read of the flag （1）
> happens-before the read of the data （2）. When the value read from
> data_ready （1） is true, the write synchronizes-with that read,
> creating a happens-before relationship. Because happens-before is
> transitive, the write to the data （3） happens-before the write to the
> flag （4）, which happens-before the read of the true value from the
> flag （1）, which happens-before the read of the data （2）, and you have
> an enforced ordering: the write of the data happens-before the read of
> the data and everything is OK. Figure 5.2 shows the important
> happens-before relationships in the two threads. I’ve added a couple
> of iterations of the while loop from the reader thread.
>
> All this might seem fairly intuitive: of course the operation that
> writes a value happens before an operation that reads that value! With
> the default atomic operations, that’s indeed true (which is why this
> is the default), but it does need spelling out: the atomic operations
> also have other options for the ordering requirements, which I’ll come
> to shortly

I quite don't understand, why "All this might seem fairly intuitive: of course the operation that writes a value happens before an operation that reads that value!", please help me to understand this statement.

Comment: Also you should put the full context including figure, or anyone doesn't has this book cannot answer your question.

Comment: You should put the full context, including whatever "all this" refers to, or else anyone with a similar question but who doesn't have this book cannot benefit from your question.

Comment: The statement describes what the author believes is a common reaction to "all this". It might help your question if you gave your reaction to "all this" -- does the stuff preceding this quote make sense to you? Does it look like it should work? Why or why not?

Comment: Hi @LouisGo, thanks for your comments. But I don't think it is all because of the loop itself. If it is because of the loop, what's the effect of the atomic here, and also the author mentions about "other options", if it is because of the loop, why says this is the default and also other options? Can't explain, right?

Comment: Hi @JaMiT, you are right, I need to put the context. Hope it will not a  infringement of copyright. I will edit and put the code fragment into description.

Comment: @LouisGo which is actually incorrect if we take in account every platform out there...  if read\write isn't atomic. Because we may read memory cache or read memory location partially during writing so reading a `true` (or any impossible value) may happen while they weren't written.

Comment: After reading the article for more times, I can understand it a bit more then before. It gets help with both atomic and the loop. As for atomic, there is a synchronizes-with relationship, so the write to atomic and read to atomic are synchronized, and with the help of loop, then can say writes happens before read.

Answer (score 0):

The operation that writes value (3) happens after the operation that reads the value (2) because of the `data_ready` flag. The writer thread enables the flag (4) after the write operation, while the reader thread has a loop that does not continue before the flag is enabled.

The compiler treats an atomic load or store as a memory fence. With the default options of an atomic variable, the compiler does not reorder operations across this fence. So the order is always 3 -> 4 -> (loop ends) -> 2.

With other options the compiler might reorder the operations in each function so that 4 is executed before 3, or 2 is executed before 1.

You can give the options as parameter to `load()` or `store()`. [See the documentation.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

Comment: If there is no loop, will load execute after store?
Actually, in the loop, the load may execute lots of times, but reads "false" as store is not execute, that's why it waits for another loop.

Comment: So, if there is no loop, will it happen  load(1)->(2)->(3)->(4).

Comment: @Jerry.J Without loop, there are several possible paths, because the two threads are being executed simultaneously: 1234, 1342, 1324, 3412, 3124, 3142 are all possible. With loop, (1) can be executed at any time, multiple times. However the loop will not end before (4) has finished. The loop is needed so that (2) is not executed before (4).